# NSMenuItem how to set maxWidth

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am new to Swift for mac and currently I have an NSMenu, which autoresizes in width, when the menu items are long. However, I would like to set a max width, either for NSMenu or NSMenuItem. The NSMenu is created in created programmatically.
Currently, I have tried the setFrameSize or setBoundsSize, but they do nothing or trying setting an NSView with a new rect, but erases all the options that existed on the menu

```
var menuItems = myMenu.items
        menuItems.forEach { item in
            let title = item.title
            
            //let autoresizingMask: NSView.AutoresizingMask = [.minXMargin, .minYMargin, .maxXMargin, .maxYMargin]
            //item.view?.setBoundsSize(NSSize(width: 100, height: 32)) //= NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 32)
            item.view?.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 100, height: 32))
            item.view?.needsDisplay = true
```

or

```
let v = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 32))
var menuItems = myMenu.items
            menuItems.forEach { item in
                item.view = v
}
```

I am not sure if changing the view is the right thing to do or if I am overwriting the existing view that way. Is there a more straight way to set max width for NSMenu?

EDIT:
The text is already automatically truncated, but still exceeds the preferable max Width limit.

Comment: The easiest is to truncate the title. Alternatively there is this solution (Objective-C, but relatively easily to adapt to Swift): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859781/nsmenuitem-truncation-and-setlinebreakmode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSMenuItem : Truncation and setLineBreakMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859781/nsmenuitem-truncation-and-setlinebreakmode)